# Convert String to Date using a specific format

Tags: java, android, date

I have this date as String:

2013-08-07T11:08:45.000+02:00

I need to convert to Date using SimpleDateFormat  but I have problem with the format .

Comment: Give us more details, what is the exception, for starters

Comment: I don't know the format into SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ as said here : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code...i u add next date...

```
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); 
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
ChangeDate = formatter.format(date);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
try{
    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(ChangeDate));
} catch (Exception e) {

}
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
ChangeDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're setting the time zone:

```
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

or something more appropriate. Also, test out explicitly specifying the locale in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong timezone format in your example, should be:

```
2013-08-07T11:08:45.000+0200
```

with pattern:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
```